# libgcc_s.so: Error adding symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, linker

When using GCC like `gcc -march i486 -m32 -e Harimain -o bootpack.hrb bootpack.c hankaku.c naskfunc.o`, the compiler worked well. But when I add `-T link.ls` it told me:

> libgcc_s.so:Error adding symbols:File in wrong format

I am creating 32bit binary on 64bit PC. This is my linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary");
SECTIONS
{
    .head 0x0 : {
        LONG(0x64 * 1024)  /*  0 : stack+.data+heap の大きさ（4KBの倍数） */
        LONG(0x69726148)      /*  4 : シグネチャ "Hari" */
        LONG(0)               /*  8 : mmarea の大きさ（4KBの倍数） */
        LONG(0x310000)        /* 12 : スタック初期値＆.data転送先 */
        LONG(SIZEOF(.data))   /* 16 : .dataサイズ */
        LONG(LOADADDR(.data)) /* 20 : .dataの初期値列のファイル位置 */
        LONG(0xE9000000)      /* 24 : 0xE9000000 */
        LONG(main - 0x20) /* 28 : エントリアドレス - 0x20 */
        LONG(0)               /* 32 : heap領域（malloc領域）開始アドレス */
}
   .text : { *(.text) }
   .data 0x310000 : AT ( ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text) ) {
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.bss)
}   /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) }
}
```

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit and GCC version is 5.4.0.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe [How can I install both 32 and 64 bit versions of the same -dev package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/254754) and [Despite Multiarch settings, Ubuntu 16.04 fails to keeping both 32 bit and 64 bit libraries installed in OS](https://askubuntu.com/q/813125)

Comment: sudo apt-get install glibc-devel.i686

Comment: You should probably post this as an answer. Also see [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) on Meta.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC builds shared programs by default. So try adding `-static` to your command line. You will probably want also `-ffreestanding`.

My advice when doing these kind of things is to separate the compile and the linker commands, and do the linker using `ld`, not `gcc`. `gcc` assumes too many things when doing the linker phase.

Comment: but when I use ld, I cannot compile them as 32bit binary file.I want to built as binary format of 32bit.How can I do it?

Comment: @石原秀一: Oh, yeah... I think that you'll need `-m elf_i386` in the linker command to switch to 32 bits. Or maybe  `-m i386linux`? I think that they only differ in the linker script and you are replacing it, so it won't matter much.

Comment: thank you, I don't want to create in elf format.just like you see the linker I just add header in my original version so when I do that it will be overlapped, I just want to create in binary format

Comment: @石原秀一: Using linker options `-m elf_i386 -T link.ls` will not create an ELF file, but a 32bit binary file, just as you want it. The `-m` option selects the _emulation mode_, that provides CPU, architecture, default format and other options, then your linker script changes the format to binary and all should be as you want.

Comment: it said cannot find lc

Comment: @石原秀一: Sorry, but I don't understand that last comment. What command did you run and what was the output?

Comment: I runned -m elf_i386 -T link.ls and it said cannot find -lc

Comment: @石原秀一: You are adding `-lc` to the linker command, aren't you? If you want to link to a 32bit library you have to say the directory. `ld` will only look by default in the 64-bit ones. So add `-L/lib/i386-linux-gnu` or whatever the directory where `libc.a` is. Alternatively you can link to the `libc.a` file directly adding the full path: instead of `-L<path> -lc` just do `<path>/libc.a`.

Comment: I added i-L/lib/i386-linux-gnu, my computer tells me that  undefined referance

Comment: I did what you ld said undfined reference to printf,Sprint/elf

Comment: @石原秀一: Well, I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve... You either use the standard C library or you do not. If you do, you can link with `gcc` but your linker script will be incomplete; if you do not, then `printf` and friends will not be available, unless you link in an alternative implementation...

Comment: Sorry,please forgive my poor english skill and IT skill.I want to use both gcc standard Liblary and linker script.I am just reading a book about creating os.I just compile it without any change but It dosen't work.So I am asking question here.

Comment: If I can, I want to send all code for you.But I don't know wether you want or not.

Comment: @石原秀一: No need to see all the code... If you are writing your own OS, then linking standard C libraries _for Linux_ will not work (with the exception of `libgcc_s`) . You need to write your own library and link that.. You can copy the source code from libc or from the linux kernel, of course, but be aware of the license!

Comment: sorry I didnot tell you.I want to use sprintf to show letters not printf

Comment: @石原秀一: `sprintf` or `printf`, the problem is the same, you just cannot link a user-mode Linux library into your custom OS kernel. However, you can copy&paste the source code of `sprintf` into your own library. A few tweaks will be needed, though.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I slove the proplem by making sprintf by my self and all is done.

Comment: @rodrigo why can't I link custom OS with linux lib. I am a new beginner. Could you give me some reference doc？because this demo is from a book, and built on win32, it works well. Is there some difference about linux and Windows？

Comment: @wangsir: I don't know what that book says, but my guess is that it links `libgcc_s`. That is OS agnostic and it can, and probably should, be linked: it has implementations for `memcpy`, `memset` and so on. What you cannot link when you are writing a homebrew OS is OS specific stuff. In `libc` you have for example `printf` that requires OS support to write to the standard output.

Comment: @rodrigo Thank you.I have the same problem with @石原秀一.It took me several days.At first I thought it was because of the error options of  `ld`。According to what you said,it is just the difference of win7 and Ubuntu.The codes has been commited to [repo](https://github.com/wangwanchao/os_30day),Could you give me some advice?